# Aligning 360 images to Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

[image: Unaligned screenshot]

We're having trouble matching the Forge Cameras Pitch, Roll, Yaw and FOV to a 360 image taken from a matching location using the Pannellum 360 viewer.

Unfortunately, the 360 image outputs its Pitch, Roll and Yaw in Axis Angle Radians which are proving an issue to Translate.

But even with our other camera outputting P, R and Y we're having trouble matching the FOVs together.

The Axis angle data for the example used is 0.013378532380583829 0.025553851466554485 0.99958392121250483 54.307948 and our conversion has set the Pitch and Roll to (Pitch of 0.0128956 Degrees) (Roll of 1.50847)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi Scott, do your 360 images include information about the **position** and **FOV** of the camera? Based on what you're describing I'd try and make sure that the viewer camera is positioned properly, and only then I'd worry about rotating it using the pitch/roll/yaw values.

Comment: All 360 images include an X,Y,Z for the position so it should be accurate. FOV we've nearly fixed but we just can't nail the Rotation aspect